# What does "mass" signify in "Weapons of Mass Destruction"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

Since "mass" can mean either **weight** or **large groups of people**, I am suddenly confused with this phrase.

Does "mass" in "weapons of mass destruction" imply:

- heavy (pertaining to mass), metaphorically indicating the weight of destruction?

  > weapons that cause "heavy destruction" (on general terms, emphasis on scale of destruction)

or

- destruction of people's (referred to as mass) lives?

  > weapons that kill a lot of "people" (emphasis on people)

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=weapons+of+mass+destruction

Comment: If you see this way, people will also have some mass or weight associated with them.

Comment: Mass does not mean "weight" in either interpretation of the meaning.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal - I understand the meaning of the phrase. If you think you can unload your sarcasm here, please feel free to. When you're done, please try to leave any useful comments that would alleviate my confusion. An answer, perhaps, that would elucidate, why my thinking is wrong, if it is wrong?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal- That would be considered more like an interesting pun on the original meaning which means widespread destruction *en masse* as it were.

Comment: @phoog - My line of thought : "The weight or scale of destruction caused by such weapons". Is it wrong?

Comment: "Mass" means "large amount".  "He had a mass of chewing gum in his mouth."

Comment: @HotLicks - Thanks. That helped. I assumed that it could signify the scale of destruction caused. I was wrong. I am happy that I understood and learned something.

Comment: A "weapon of mass destruction" means that there is a large scale of destruction, beyond the range of perhaps a thousand meters that would be the limit for "conventional" bombs, etc (though I doubt that there is a specific "threshold" for the distance).  The weapons encompassed by this category are basically nuclear weapons plus large poison gas weapons.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Sorry, but I was not trying to be sarcastic here. I didn't use any smiley face, did I? Ridiculing you was not my intention. By the google link, I wanted to tell you that it was about loss of life but actually, I properly understood your question after your edit only.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal I was not intending to demand precision about mass vs. weight. Rather, I don'tthink the physical concept is in play here.  I was thinking more along the lines of HotLicks's comment, although I didn't articulate it as clearly, that "mass means 'large amount.'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **mass** in your example is an adjective used attributively. According to [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mass), it means as an adjective:

> [Attributive] Involving or affecting large numbers of people or things: *the film has
> mass appeal*, *a mass exodus of refugees*

According to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mass), it started to be used as an adjective from 1733 and it further explains:

> first attested in **mass meeting** in American English. **mass culture** is
> from 1916 in sociology (earlier in biology); **mass hysteria** is from
> 1914; **mass media** is from 1923; **mass movement** is from 1897; **mass
> production** is from 1920; **mass grave** is from 1918; **mass murder** from
> 1880.

The dictionary also has an etymology of [**weapons of mass destruction**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=weapons+of+mass+destruction&allowed_in_frame=0):

> "nuclear, biological and chemical weapons" attested by 1946,
> apparently first used (in Russian) by the Soviets.
>
> The terms "weapons
> of mass destruction" and "WMD" mean chemical, biological, and nuclear
> weapons, and chemical, biological, and nuclear materials used in the
> manufacture of such weapons. [United States Code: Title 50, "War and
> National Defense," chapter 43, § 2902, 2009]

Comment: Thanks. +1. "Attributive adjective" is what I was looking for. :) Merry Christmas to you! :D